# Qt Events after a long routine freezes my application for a while

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling

So, I have a single-threaded application which loads data from a set of file:

```
QStringList qFiles = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(
    this,
    "Choose Image Files",
    "",
    "Dicom Files(*.dcm);;All Files(*)"
);
```

After that I invoke a library which will parse the set of files, since the library invokes OpenGL functions I may not create a new thread for this processing. 
Once this processing is done I noticed my application froze for a while.

Using GDB I noticed my Qt Application buffered a lot of Events while the library processed the set of files and then it is processing these events.

I may not invoke QApplication::instance()->processEvents() inside the libary, because it doesnt know Qt(project decision).

Is there way to discard these events? Or is there any other solution to keep my application from freezing?

Comment: Did you happen to notice what kind of events these were?  Also...while the library may not know Qt...might you pass it a function pointer to be called back--for instance after each file?  You could then initialize the library and pass in a function, which it calls to do event processing (even better if the callback is more meaningful or generically useful).

Comment: @HostileFork Take a look at the stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/VEma6KE7  It looks like glib is saving recently accessed files info to the disk. The weird is that it does it a lot of times...

Comment: What exactly is the reason that you can't move the OpenGL rendering to a separate thread?

Answer (score 1):

### Move OpenGL Rendering to a Worker Thread

If possible, move your OpenGL rendering to a separate thread.  Then you can call your library functions there and not worry about them blocking the event queue.

You should be able to devote your framebuffer to the worker thread and communicate with it using signals and slots just fine.

### Alternative: Implement Progress Callbacks

Alternatively you could see if the library has any callbacks.  If you have source available, you could implement your own during long-running operations.

Comment: I agree with you, also a Progress Callback is already begin made. But I need some thing faster for now, I was wondering if is there anyway to discard these events.